# External JAR in Android Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I'm trying to add an animation framework by [nhaarman](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/blob/master/README.md) called ListViewAnimations. I have tried adding it to the build path as an external JAR, I have tried coping it to the libs folder and adding it as a JAR though build path, and regardless of what I do, when I run the program, it gives me the following error:

```
10-08 17:20:59.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2024): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 17:20:59.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2024): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.haarman.listviewanimations.swinginadapters.prepared.AlphaInAnimationAdapter
10-08 17:20:59.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2024):     at com.fthatnoise.borrow.me.BorrowMeHome.onCreate(BorrowMeHome.java:71)
10-08 17:20:59.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2024):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-08 17:20:59.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2024):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-08 17:20:59.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-08 17:20:59.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-08 17:20:59.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-08 17:20:59.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2024):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-08 17:20:59.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2024):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-08 17:20:59.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2024):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-08 17:20:59.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-08 17:20:59.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2024):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 17:20:59.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2024):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-08 17:20:59.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2024):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-08 17:20:59.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2024):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-08 17:20:59.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2024):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I know this error is because the project cannot find the library, but I'm not sure why.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, is Eclipse throwing errors on lines where you're attempting to use the class, or is it just on run?

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, copy it in by **dragging and dropping into `libs` in the GUI**, not through Explorer/Finder.

Comment: @AnthonyAtkinson When I use the class, it finds it just fine. The error occurs when running the project.

Answer (score 1):

You were doing right adding the `jar` to `libs` folder, but you have to make sure is not also added to your build path. A full project clean might help as well.

Comment: So if I drag it to my libs folder, I don't have to add it to the build  path?

Comment: Actually, you cannot. Since last ADT versions, external dependencies are managed through libs folder; adding jars to build path will only give you problems.

Comment: Ok, I have removed it and cleared all the build path, and simply re added it to the libs folder, but it is still giving me the same message.

Comment: Mmh did you remove the application from device and reinstall?

Comment: I did indeed, still the same. It's very frustrating.

Comment: In these cases, I try everything until it just works: changing android version on Android properties, clicking on fix project properties, double check that `Android private libraries` and `Android dependencies` are checked in Build path `Order and export path`, formatting computer hard drive (just joking)

Comment: Sounds good. I'll try everything, see what happens. Hopefully it won't come to the last one!

Comment: Hello @Niek, sorry for the late reply, As of yet, it has not. Im going to try again tonight to make it work.

Comment: Man this sucks. Tried everything and it still doesn't work. Might just have to give up on this library.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Seemed to be an issue with the git branch. When I changed it back to the master branch and re-added it it seemed to work.

Very Strange.

Thanks for all the help!